# Python: How to combine the results of for loop into one output?

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration, output

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]

for number in numbers:
   number = number * 2 

#For the output I will get:
2
4
6
```

How do I modify my code so the results can be combined (eg. [2, 4, 6]) without using the print statement?

Comment: Do you mean you do *not* want to output the result?  Only calculate it?

Comment: I don't know what you mean "# For the output I will get: 2 4 6". There is no output here at all. And no effect; all you're doing each time through the loop is reassigning the loop variable `number` to a different value, which you then immediately forget.

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing the Python interpreter's behavior of displaying `return`ed values with the built-in `print()` function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[num*2 for num in numbers]
```

---

```
>>> numbers = [1, 2, 3]
>>> [num*2 for num in numbers]
[2, 4, 6]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create new List type variable `result` and add values into it by list `append()` method.

Demo:

```
>>> numbers = [1, 2, 3]
>>> result = []
>>> for i in numbers:
...   result.append(i*2)
... 
>>> result
[2, 4, 6]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to gather the results into a list, you just create a list and `append` each one onto it:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
doubles = []
for number in numbers:
    double = number * 2 
    doubles.append(double)
```

… or, more compactly, do the same with a list comprehension:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
doubles = [number * 2 for number in numbers]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put ,end=" "  at the end of ur print function to print all in one line

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).